# How to get and print a specific same value to entry in HashMap

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

for example I have below my HashMap, keys (Integer) and values(Integer also):

```
HashMap <Integer, Integer> mymap = new HasHmap <> ();
mymap.put(1, 3);
mymap.put(2, 4);
mymap.put(3, 1);
mymap.put(4, 5);
mymap.put(5, 2);
```

Print output: `match found! [1,3]  [3,1]`

Is it possible to find and print a match like this in my HashMap? Can you teach me how to?

Comment: What is exactly you are trying to achieve? And please add some code of what you've tried

Comment: Well yes it is possible. Just look at the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code, but you can workaround with similar kind of approach.

The output is

1 -> 3

3 -> 1

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

class GfG {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1, 3);
        map.put(2, 3);
        map.put(5, 3);
        map.put(3, 1);
        map.put(6, 3);
        Set<Entry<Integer, Integer>> entry = map.entrySet();
        for(Entry<Integer, Integer> e: entry){
            int key = e.getKey();
            int value = e.getValue();
            if(map.containsKey(value) && map.get(value) != null && map.get(value) == key){
                System.out.println(key +" -> "+value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot!! though I understand the flow, but can you explain me    the Set<k,v> = HashMap.entrySet(); and the condition for if() statement, im just in the learning curve of Hashmap :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and it is as simple as:

```
// loop over every entry
for (Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : mymap.entrySet()) {
    // look up for current value, and check if it is equal to the key
    if (mymap.get(entry.getValue()).equals(entry.getKey())) {
        // it's a match!
        System.out.println("[" + entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue() + "]");
        // stop after first match (asked in comments)
        break;
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: ok this is much cleaner and thanks :D, what if for example I have more than 1 match and I only want to print the 1st match that found?

Comment: Simply add a `break` statement, see my edited answer.

Comment: @RYREN why is it no longer the accepted answer? The other is way slower (3 lookups instead of one), contains useless code, and is using `==` against objects, which is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28953839/).

Comment: yes sir it is indeed faster thanks, but when i tried the given entryKeys be a userinput = 0, it says null

Comment: @RYREN sorry, I didn't understand what issue you have faced, and how the other solution could have worked if mine failed. Please could you explain more?